# Can I send Push Notifications to Other Devices with APNS Dev iOS certificate?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I have a Development APNs iOS Certificate for my new app, and from my server I am successfully sending push notifications and receiving them on own iPhone, using the device token.  I have a partner in this app development, and I create an `.ipa` file of the app and give it to him for testing.  This is called ad-hoc development.  It has worked for us thus far.

From my server it looks like I am successfully sending out the push notification to his device as well as mine, using HIS device token of course (but using the same Dev APNs Cert), but he never receives the notifications.   I still continue to receive my notifications.  I also have registered his device in my dev center.  He does not have a developer account.

So after reading up a little I am thinking that maybe with this APNs Dev certificate it is impossible to send notifications to third party devices, like my partner's device in this case.  I was thinking perhaps I need to create a DISTRIBUTION certificate.  Is this true?  Or should the notifications work for many devices just using the APNs Dev certificate?

Thanks

Comment: If you use archive to pack the adhoc build, it is a release build and you need to send APNs with distribution certificate and sending to the distribution APNs server. If you setup the stuff as a team or by export / import the developer account st he can also build and install the development app on his device, you can send using development certificate.

Comment: Well my workflow is usually to first archive the project, and then from the organizer window I click the export button.  This produces the file that I send to the partner.

Comment: Okay, you send an archive ipa which is indeed a distribution build, please setup your APNs server part with distribution certificate and send to feedback.push.apple.com (instead of feedback.sandbox.push.apple.com with development cert).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pushes go out over two environments - development and production and they are not interchangeable - i.e. if you send out a push to the Apple development server intended for a release build app it won't work and vice versa.
Apps installed and run via Xcode are debug builds and you need to send the push via the dev server, an app built for distribution is a prod build and thus the pushes need to go to the prod server.

As you are probably aware the url for the two servers is different.

Needless to say the server needs to be signed with both the prod and dev push certificates for the server to be able to send pushes on both environment.

BTW the two environments do not behave the same in terms of delivery speed etc. But this is only really noticeable for silent pushes, where bizarrely the dev environment is better than the prod one.

Comment: The new Apple Push Services Certificate contains both sandbox and prod environments, There is no more need to create two different certificates.

Comment: yes I have been reading through the docs, I know about the sandbox URL as opposed to the distribution.  Thanks!  I was just wondering, since to me what we are doing still seems like development, not distribution, since there are only 2 people working on it, is there a way I can get my partner the test app as a development version, where the dev push notifications will work?

Comment: If you look here, step 2, there is a "Save for Development Deployment" option shown. You could give that a try and see if it works https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html

Comment: Yes I can confirm this works, if you select to export for development instead of ad-hoc, you can use the sandbox notification server instead of the distribution server.  Very cool.